# Is there T4 templates available for generating c# classes from xsd?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xsd, .net-4.0, t4

Is there T4 templates available for generating c# classes from xsd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I know of, but take a look at LINQ to XSD (http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/).  You can use LinqToXsd.exe to generate strongly typed classes based on your schema.  And then you have full LINQ support as well.  Very handy.

You could also set up a pre-build event on your project that looks something like:

`"$(ProjectDir)Lib/LinqToXsd/LinqToXsd.Exe" "$(ProjectDir)MySchema.xsd" /fileName:MySchema.cs`

And that would generate the classes from the schema right before you build, so if you change your schema, your classes will stay in sync with each build.

Comment: Nice, didn't know that.  Much better than a pre build step.

Comment: You can also use the Build Action property of the XSD file in the Solution Explorer, and set it to LinqToXsdSchema (this requires that you set up the project to import LinqToXsd.targets)

Answer (score 3):

I just built a very simple one today that should do the trick.

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Windows.Forms.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.CSharp" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Serialization" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Schema" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.CodeDom" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.CodeDom.Compiler" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.CSharp" #>
<# 
    // directory of this template
    var outputDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);

    // iterate through each XSD file in our /Schema/ directory
    // and output the generated C# file in this directory.
    foreach(var file in new DirectoryInfo(Host.ResolvePath("Schemas")).GetFiles("*.xsd")) {

        // ouput file should be the directory of this template, with .Generated.cs
        var outputFile = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, file.Name.Replace(".xsd", ".Generated.cs"));

        // do it
        File.WriteAllText(outputFile, GenerateFromXsd(file.FullName));
    }
#>
<#+
    private string GenerateFromXsd(string xsdFileName)
    {
        // load the xsd
        XmlSchema xsd;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(xsdFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            xsd = XmlSchema.Read(stream, null);
        }

        var xsds = new XmlSchemas();
        xsds.Add(xsd);
        xsds.Compile(null, true);

        var schemaImporter = new XmlSchemaImporter(xsds);

        // create the codedom
        var codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace((string)System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.LogicalGetData("NamespaceHint"));
        var codeExporter = new XmlCodeExporter(codeNamespace);

        var maps = new List<object>();
        foreach (XmlSchemaType schemaType in xsd.SchemaTypes.Values)
        {
            maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportSchemaType(schemaType.QualifiedName));
        }
        foreach (XmlSchemaElement schemaElement in xsd.Elements.Values)
        {
            maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportTypeMapping(schemaElement.QualifiedName));
        }
        foreach (XmlTypeMapping map in maps)
        {
            codeExporter.ExportTypeMapping(map);
        }

        // Check for invalid characters in identifiers
        CodeGenerator.ValidateIdentifiers(codeNamespace);

        // output the C# code
        var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            codeProvider.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(codeNamespace, writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
            return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
#>
```