# How to convert XSD to C# including comments in XSD?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xsd.exe

We have an XSD that we consider "self documenting" in that each enum includes a friendly description.

E.g.

```
  <xs:simpleType name="CarType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:enumeration value="02">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Volvo</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:enumeration>
  <xs:enumeration value="01">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Saab</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:enumeration>
```

...

The problem is that when we run the above xsd through the Visual Studio xsd.exe tool, we end up with C# that looks like this:

```
public enum CarType {

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("02")]
Item02,

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("01")]
Item01,
```

In other words, the nice < documentation > tags are lost.

What is the solution?

Comment: Write your own version of xsd.exe. It’s functionality is based on built in .net libraries. You can call these libraries and get a Code DOM from an xsd. Then parse through the xsd and add the comments to the code DOM. I have a project where we do just this. We also apply all sorts of other customizations.

Comment: See this answer for a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11907067/